# Convert SharePoint Custom List in Datasheet View to a Regular Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, datasheet

I created a custom list in datasheet view and populated it with a fairly large number of items.

I am now discovering a few limitations with this list type versus a the standard SharePoint custom list (the new user friendly automate rules, and integration with Lists in Teams).

**Is there any easy way to convert any existing custom list in datasheet view to a regular custom list?**

This would save a ton of time if I don't have to recreate the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to convert existing list in datasheet view to a regular custom list.

As a workaround, you could export data from existing list by using "Export to Excel", then create a list by using "Import Spreadsheet" in the site contents.